# Understanding Objects when using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0

I saw something weird, from the point that was not what I was expecting.

Let's take this simple code to allow you to see what I did:

```
MyRepository db = new MyRepository();

// let's get them all
IQueryable<TblCals> cals = db.FindAllCalendars();

// now that we have everything, let's split up
List<TblCals> masters = cals.Where(x => x.IsMaster).ToList();
List<TblCals> childs =  cals.Where(x => x.Parent > 0).ToList();

// Let's change the name of the masters
foreach(var c in masters) c.Name = String.Concat("Master: ", c.Name);

// Let's send everything to the View
return View(new model() { masters, childs });
```

Now, **the problem**:

Why does the name changing in the `List` `masters` does also change the name of the objects that are in the `childs`?

When I do `List<TblCals> masters = cals.Where(x => x.IsMaster).ToList();` shouldn't this copy the elements instead of only referencing them from the `cals` object?

> **What can I do** to prevent this behavior?

I could simple do:

```
MyRepository db = new MyRepository();

// let's get them all
IQueryable<TblCals> cals = db.FindAllCalendars();

// now that we have everything, let's split up
List<TblCals> masters = db.FindAllCalendarsThatAreMasters().ToList();
List<TblCals> childs =  db.FindAllCalendarsThatHaveParent().ToList();
```

but **this will end up being 3 queries to the database**, and I could simply get all first and then use that object... but not if the "master" object keeps changing when I change any sub query from it.

---

The major idea behind all this, is to see if it is safe to do:

```
public IEnumerable<JK_Users> ListAllUsers() {
    // Check / Add to memcache
    string key = "ListAllUsers";
    var users = MemcachedLayer.Get<IEnumerable<JK_Users>>(key);

    if(key == null)
        users = db.Tbl_Users.CachedQuery(key);

    return users;
}

public IEnumerable<JK_Users> FindUserById(decimal id) {
    // call ListAllUsers() instead Repository
    return this.ListAllUsers().FirstOrDefault(x => x.user_id == id);
}
public IEnumerable<JK_Users> FindUserByUsername(string username) {
    // call ListAllUsers() instead Repository
    return this.ListAllUsers().FirstOrDefault(x => x.username == username);
}
```

or I do have to call

```
public JK_Users FindUserById(decimal id) {
    return db.Tbl_Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.user_id == id);
}
public JK_Users FindUserByUsername(string username) {
    return db.Tbl_Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.username == username);
}
```

So I can use the Cache more efficiently.

Comment: Why don't you just display the prefix "Master: " in the view for calendars that have IsMaster set to true? Or is this just an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, collections only ever contain references for reference types. There's nothing EF-specific here:

```
List<StringBuilder> list1 = new List<StringBuilder>();
List<StringBuilder> list2 = new List<StringBuilder>();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
list1.Add(builder);
list2.Add(builder);
list1[0].Append("Foo");
Console.WriteLine(list2[0]); // Still prints Foo...
```

The entity framework is ensuring that for any one "entity", there's only a single object (within the context of your repository object). That means you can't get into the state where you've changed the same field on two different objects representing the same entity (where entity is defined by its ID).

This really is the logical approach - think of the values involved as entities; your two queries match the same entities for some results... why would you *want* those two results for the same entity to be independent objects? If someone refers to "Jon Skeet of Stack Overflow" and "Jon Skeet of Tilehurst, Reading, UK" that's the same person - changing (say) the age via one result *should* change the age when seen via the other result.

Comment: so I really need to make 3 database calls to get what I need? ... is there any way to make it more efficient? - In my case it's about getting a `Master` that is also a `Parent` being the hole idea to drastically reduce the calls to the database.

Comment: @balexandre: Firstly you need to be aware that creating an `IQueryable<T>` is *not* making a database call, contrary to what your comment suggests in the question. You then need to think about whether you *really* want to violate the entity model in the way you're suggesting. What is the name *of the entity* here? It sounds like you should be taking a step back and thinking about your overall design more carefully, rather than focusing on this specific issue.

Comment: right, forgot that brilliant part, `IQueryable` is just a query, only when I do `ToList()` in this case, that's the true database call.

Comment: I just appended some code that I'm currently using, will it be safe to use the approach where I fill up from `Cache` or I need to call my repository every time? ... this was what I had in mind when asked this question.

Comment: @balexandre: I suspect the caching won't work, as I would expect each entity to "know" the context it was loaded from. You may be able to detach it from that context though. This is beyond my knowledge of Entity Framework to be honest - I suggest you get a good book or tutorial on it.